# CreateObjectUrl of Javascript file object from Cordova camera

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

In our app, users can attach images and they will be saved locally to be uploaded later. We need to be able to display a thumbnail of the attached images.

For Android, we are retrieving images from the Cordova camera plugin using File_Uri and storing the javascript File object in the local db. However, when I try to show a thumbnail of that image using window.URL.createObjectURL() on that File object, it fails with "Type Error".

This works fine on a desktop browsers when using files that the user attached to a file input, but for some reason the files that Cordova is giving us on Android aren't working.

I know that I could change this to use FileReader and it does work that way, but that would require changing a bunch of other code (not shown here) that is shared with our Windows and web html5 apps so we would like to avoid changing the approach if possible.

Here is a trimmed down version of the code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (fileUrl) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUrl, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            // Save File
            // ...

            // Get DataUrl of image
            dataUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        });
    });
}, function (error) {
    alert(error);
}, {
    quality: 40,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
});
```

It fails on images retrieved from the camera and the photo album. Is there something I am doing wrong here? The debugger shows that the file object is a Javascript File object (which is what we want), but for some reason it fails to create the object url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PhoneGap File plugin (a dependency of many other plugins, including camera) replaces the native `File` implementation with its own. This replacement is not an instance of (does not inherit from) `Blob`, so the `createObjectURL` method fails as you discovered.

You can use the `localURL` field of a `File` to get something suitable for ie an `<img>` tag, but in your case that would be somewhat circular. I'd set up your thumbnail prior to calling `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` at all:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (fileUrl) {

    // just grab this here
    dataUrl = fileUrl;

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUrl, function (fileEntry) {

        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            // Do your other work here
            // ...
        });
    });
}, function (error) {
alert(error);
}, {
    quality: 40,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false    
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  That makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score -2):

I think `window.URL` is firefox specific. Try `window.webkitURL`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but window.URL is working fine in Chrome and IE 11.